# Git - Rewriting history to remove one file from a prior multi-file commit in one branch

Tags: git, version-control, url-rewriting, history

Setup: I've inherited a repo that has a old development branch (call it `oldDev`) that was taken from another (call it `master`).

`oldDev` lived for awhile and has some **partial** manual merges of `master` in it and its own divergent development (with the inter-mix of manual `master` merges and original changes, rebasing is not an option). `oldDev` has come back to life, so merging from `master` into `oldDev` are taking place to bring it feature compatible with `master`. This spans multiple years of major/minor 'release' tags involving thousands of changed files. ;-)

> Question: Within those thousands of changed files, I have developed a list of files that need to only track the `master` and not be part of the changed file commits in `oldDev`.

So how do you rewrite history to remove a 'single' file an older multi-file commit in one branch? Thus the history (changes and content) of that file are only based upon the `master` branch and not `oldDev`.

Note: I am not looking to DELETE that file from the branch, it should still exist, now based upon the flow of the original branch (`master`).

Update:

```
M - M1(F1)(F2) - M2(F1)(F2) - M3(F1)(F2) - M4(F1)(F2)
 \
  X - X1(F'1)(F2) - X2(F'1)(F'2) - X3(F'1)(F'2)
```

In branch X, remove the file changes F'2 from the X2 commit so only F'1 is in that commit (thus 'reverting' F'2 to F2 from the prior commit).

```
M - M1(F1)(F2) - M2(F1)(F2) - M3(F1)(F2) - M4(F1)(F2)
 \
  X - X1(F'1)(F2) - X2(F'1)(F2) - X3(F'1)(F2)
```

Comment: Can you add a diagram showing exactly what you want? Your question is a bit vague.  Please show us the workflow you want with one single file between the `OldDev` and `Master` branches.

Comment: With no answers from anyone, am I to assume that this can not be done within git history rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

> I to assume that this can not be done within git history rewriting

If should be possible, with [`git filter-branch --tree-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#git-filter-branch---tree-filterltcommandgt), in which you can do a:

```
git checkout aster -- afile
```

That would replace that file content (in the `oldDev` branch) with the one from `master`.